# JS - meaning of @ in import '@foo/bar'

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-module-loader

While reading this [article](https://medium.com/@fkrautwald/plug-and-play-all-your-observable-streams-with-cycle-js-e543fc287872) earlier, I came across the following line of code:

```
import { run } from '@cycle/core';
```

Which led me to the following questions:

- What is the significance of the `@` symbol, if any?
- Is there a difference between `import 'foo/bar'` and `import '@foo/bar'`?

Is it a way to resolve a particular type of module?

I'm relatively new to ES6, although the `import` syntax seems pretty straightforward to me - except, in this case, for the cryptic presence of the `@` symbol.

I tried googling but couldn't find any information on Stack Overflow, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) or elsewhere.

Comment: From node.js point of view, `@cycle/core` is just a name of [an npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cycle/core), so node.js is just loading whatever is installed into `node_modules/@cycle/core` folder.

Comment: Thanks @LeonidBeschastny :)

Comment: This actually isn't specified by ES6, only your module loader knows how to interpret the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right from the [Getting Started](https://cycle.js.org/getting-started.html) docs:

> Packages of the type **@org/package are npm scoped packages**, supported
>   if your npm installation is version 2.11 or higher. Check your npm
>   version with npm --version and upgrade in order to install Cycle.js.
>
> In case you are not dealing with a DOM-interfacing web application,
>   you can omit @cycle/dom when installing.

Comment: Boom. That was incredibly fast. Thanks @Álvaro! Yeah, I never really thought to look into the cycle.js docs themselves - and clearly my google-fu is lacking. For anyone else curious there is some information on scoped packages on the [NPM blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/116936804365/solving-npms-hard-problem-naming-packages) and a more in-depth discussion [here](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/a-summary-of-scoped-modules-in-npm/).